# How to create a campaign Buy 2 get 1 free in drupal commerce?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-commerce

How to create buy 2 get 1 free in drupal 7 Commerce? I tried commerce discount module but that is buggy and in alpha version right now.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the module [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules).
With this module, we had allowed the user to purchase only one item.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following link. You can achieve your required functionality with the Rules integration.
http://www.slideshare.net/richard_jones_ikos/promotions-in-drupal-commerce

Answer (score -2):

Please use commerce discount module in drupal 7 .

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_discount

Go to store -> Discounts -> Add discounts

Choose discount types-> order discounts

Choose offer types -> Free products

Comment: The discount module doesn't have a 'Free' product type and the OP wasnt asking to give away Free products but to give one free if two were purchased.